# Let $p=(-1,0)$, $q=(0,0)$ and $r=(3,\sqrt 3)$ be three points. Find the equation of angle bisector of $PQR$

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Slope of $PQ$ is $0$

Then equation of $PQ$ is 
$$y-0=0$$
$$y=0$$
Slope of $QR$ is
$\sqrt 3$
$$y-0=\sqrt 3(x-0)$$
$$\sqrt 3x-y=0$$
Equation of angle bisector 
$$\frac y1 =\frac{\sqrt 3 x-y}{2}$$
$$2y=\sqrt 3x-y$$
$$\sqrt 3x-3y =0$$
But the answer is $\sqrt 3x+y=0$ what’s going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *equation of angle*? Do you want the value of it? Or the equation of the line?

Comment: @Pspl equation of the angle bisector, which is a line that divides an angle into two equal halves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of $QR$ is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$, that's your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple making a sketch, and reasoning with polar angles:

Since the slope of the line $(QR)$ is $\frac{\sqrt 3}3$, its polar angle is $\frac\pi 6$, so the polar angle of the bissectrix of angle $\widehat{xQR}$ is $\frac\pi{12}$, and the polar angle of the bissectrix of angle $\widehat{PQR}$ is $\frac\pi{12}+\frac\pi 2$.

Therefore, the slope of this bissectrix is
$$\tan\bigl(\tfrac\pi{12}+\tfrac\pi 2\bigr)=-\frac 1{\tan\frac\pi{12}}=-(2+\sqrt 3),$$
so its equation is
$$(2+\sqrt 3)x+y=0.$$